# @OneToMany by means of mappedBy without @JoinColumns

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am founding some legacy code in my job where some of the following shows up:

For simplification, imagine a One class and a Many class.
In **One** Class I got:

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "toOne")
 private List<Many> manies;
```

But in **Many** class, the field toOne is defined as:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "unrelated", referencedColumnName = "id") 
UnrelatedEntity toOne;
```

The only plausible explanation is that toOne field has both a relation with Unrelated and also a FK to Many. But, is it possible to have a @OneToMany using mappedBy without the use of a local or remote @JoinColumn? I did not see any example using that simplification. Is it using One.@Id for the join automagically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"`mappedBy`" links the 2 sides of the relation nothing more. If you omit the `JoinColumn` then it will use a join table to manage the relation. If you use `JoinColumn` then it manages the relation via an FK in the *"many side"*. Very simple. It will use how many `@Id` fields there are in the *"1 side"* for the FK.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there is no need for '@JoinColumn' in an unidirectional '@OneToMany' with mappedBy, simply the 'One.@Id' will be used from the mappedBy field, right? It's surprising because I could not find that simplification on the JPA wiki or a brief research

Comment: There is a need if you want the relation to be managed via a FK, as said above. If you want a Join Table then omit the JoinColumn ... or put `@JoinTable`. You certainly don't need the attributes of the JoinColumn ... since the PK is used to map to the FK

Comment: Sorry for my english, it seems Many is linked to One by a FK, functionally. The thing is whether just by putting @OneToMany(mapped by) in One is enough for JPA, i.e, will infer that the field in Many points to One.@Id

Comment: Many is obviously linked to One ... BIDIRECTIONAL ... since you put mappedBy. That is enough to have a Bidirectional relation. It is NOT enough if you want to manage that relation via a FK in the Many, as said above ... put JoinColumn for that, otherwise it is managed via a JoinTable (and no FK). Read some documentation http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/orm/one_to_many_collection.html#fk_bi